# Are Firebase Auth User accounts lost if using a single GCP Region as default location in case of a disaster in that region?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, backup

With a Firebase project using GCP resources in a single Region (not dual/multi region), are Firebase Auth Users also *only* stored somehow in that region and would be lost in case of a disaster in that region?

I am backing up Firestore data (that contains additional information for accounts) as well as Storage data to Storage buckets in another region.

But I am wondering whether the Firebase Auth Accounts itself (I mean the data from the "Authentication" tab in Firebase Console, e.g. Auth Provider, UID, password-Hash parameters for each user) would be lost in case of a disaster? Let's say a fire destroys the GCP region completely the project has set as default GCP location - I can then of course restore the Firestore and Storage data but will all accounts (="logins") be lost or are they anyway always backed up/replicated across regions by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the data you store in Firestore or Storage, the user profiles in Authentication are fully managed by Firebase. I believe they're quite well globally replicated, but the point is that they're not your/my concern.

If you **do** want to create your own back up of the user data, you can do so through [the `auth:export` command of the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) or through the [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#listusers).